# Flask SQLalchemy - many to many - show photo with all tags (or blog with all posts etc)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask and SQLalchemy. Want to have web page with individual photo that shows all tags assigned to that photo.

I have SQLalchemy working fine with MYSQL db. Nicely retrieves records etc.

I need help with flask/SQLalchemy work flow:

*model -> view (input from url eg view / photo id) -> template -> web page*

The models are as follows:

```
class Photos(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(100))
    tags = db.relationship(
        'Tags', 
        secondary=photo_tags,
        backref='photos')


class Tags(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tagname = db.Column(db.String(100))

photo_tags = db.Table('photo_tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id')),
    db.Column('photo_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('photos.id'))
)
```

My view is as follows:

```
@app.route('/phototags/<int:id>')
#@login_required
def phototags(id=None):
    photo_tags =  Tags.query.filter(Tags.photos).filter(id == id).all()
    return render_template(
        'phototags.html', 
        title='PhotoTags',
        message='Your application description page.',
        photo_tags = photo_tags
    )
```

My template is as follows:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>{{ title }}.</h2>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>
            {% for phototag in photo_tags %}
            <div style="float:left; class=" img-responsive">
                <p><a href="{{ url_for('photo', id=phototag.id)}}">photo</a></p>
                <p><a href="{{ url_for('tag', id=phototag.id)}}"></p>tag</a></p>
                <img src="static/photos/{{ phototag.id }}" width="100" height="100">
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am pretty sure the models and association table/model are setup properly.

The template is not perfect, as it currently appears to show tag ids for photo ids.  I have tried to do 'phototag.photo_id' or 'phototag.filename' but doesn't come out. Obviously view query is not putting that through.

So the view is what i need help with.  Is the query correct?  and is it getting url passed parameter for photo_id correctly?

My test data is simple.  I have a single Photo record with photos.id = 1

This has 2 related Phototags records: phototags.id = 1 (tag.id = 1), phototags.id = 2 (tag.id = 2)

When I pass url http://localhost:5555/phototags/1 my view query passes tag ids, but changing the passed parameter always gets the same tag ids eg phototags/2 also gets the same two tags.  So query is obviously not correct.

I have looked at scores of examples and they all subtly different than what I want. None of the examples/tutorials/SO questions/answers i have seen show how the model, view and template work together to get what I want. They are either:

- getting opposite eg equivalent of photos by tag  (want tags by photo)
- are just query that gets the tags by photo (i don't even think i am getting that)
- have another SQLalchemy notation that includes 'sessions' or 'base' instead of 'db.model'

What I want as output is a photo id so i can show photo and its name etc and also show a list of tags associated with that photo eg as a comma separated list.

I am stumped to find a demo/example/tutorial/github project that walks me through what i need for workflow.

Can anyone show me example of view that can get photo id from url parameter and then query my models to get the associated tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems more appropriate to query a photo instead of photo_tags from what you describe about your use case.
With the view function

```
@app.route('/phototags/<int:id>')
def phototags(id=None):
    photo =  Photo.query.get(id)
    return render_template(
        'phototags.html', 
        title='PhotoTags',
        message='Your application description page.',
        photo = photo
    )
```

you can then display the photo and iterate its tags using the 'tags' relationship in the html template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>{{ title }}.</h2>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>
            <img src="static/photos/{{ photo.id }}" width="100" height="100">
            {% for phototag in photo.tags %}
            <div style="float:left; class=" img-responsive">
                <p><a href="{{ url_for('photo', id=phototag.id)}}">photo</a></p>
                <p><a href="{{ url_for('tag', id=phototag.id)}}"></p>tag</a></p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Note that I used the get function in the query for the Photo. It's basically the same as

```
Photo.query.filter(id == id).first()
```

Renaming the view function and the template from phototags to photo would also make sense.

If you wanted to display all images for a tag you have to reverse the logic, querying for a tag and iterating over the photos. Should be possible, because you defined a backref.

Comment: Ahh, ok that is too easy.  So that is how the tags association (and backref) in the Photos model can be used. I wouldn't have thought of using 'photo.tags' as I didn't know that the association could access photo_tags table via the tags association.  Makes total sense now. Thanks!