# Jinja/flask, how to show one photo at a time from a list of photos?

Tags: python, flask

The idea is to have a page where you rate a photo of a dog, and once rating is submitted, the next photo shows up. Not unlike hot or not, for dogs... I thought this part would be simple and maybe I just need to take a break and an answer will come to me.

So far i have implemented registering, logging in, a means to upload the photos, a database to store all this information(sqlite3) and other little tid bits.

The main page is "arena.html" and ive just thrown in the list of all DB photos at it in a for loop. the outcome is that all the photos show up stacked on top of each other. I would like some help to figure out a simple way to show just one photo, then after its rated, the next photo takes its place.

arena.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Arena
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock %}


{% block main %}
{% for photo in photos %}
<div><img src={{photo|replace("'", "")|replace(",", "")|replace("(", "")|replace(")", "")}} id="arena_pic" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

```
app.py
```

```
@app.route ("/arena", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def arena():
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('dogs.db')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            print("DB Init")
            sql = ("SELECT photo_address FROM photos;")
            cursor.execute(sql)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            print(rows)
            
        except sqlite3.Error as er:
            conn.rollback()
            print('SQLite error: %s' % (' '.join(er.args)))
            print("Exception class is: ", er.__class__)
            print('SQLite traceback: ')
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            print(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb))
            flash("Oops, There was an gathering error!")
            return render_template("arena.html")

        else:
            conn.close()
            return render_template("arena.html", photos = rows)
```

I thought about rendering a new template each time but i dont know how to do that dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There are some clues for you...
You may check the article first

[Flask SQLalchemy - many to many - show photo with all tags (or blog with all posts etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365261/flask-sqlalchemy-many-to-many-show-photo-with-all-tags-or-blog-with-all-pos)

And try the "jinjagrid" to batch processing as your html template. To be more clean and controllable.

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        {% for row in elements|batch(5) %}  ## batch times by your demand
        <div class="columns">
            {% for column in row %}
            <div class="column">
                <p class="notification is-danger">{{ column }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
```

Here comes the reference:
https://youtu.be/lhpNRDGzInw
https://github.com/PrettyPrinted/youtube_video_code/tree/master/2020/06/29/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Grid%20in%20a%20Jinja2%20Template

Comment: Im not following how this solves my problem. I am not using tags and am in need of dynamically reloading one new picture each time a button is pressed. The way its currently setup is that my html page receives a list of url photo links.